# Mocking child component properties jest+enzyme+react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I have a component I'm trying to mock the props child component it's referencing. The reasoning is I want to make sure the logic in my component is correctly set.

Component:

```
class Toolbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ComponentA>
                <ComponentB
                    onRenderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
            </ComponentA>
        );
    }

    renderItem() {
        return (
            <ComponentC
                onChange={(event) => {
                    // logic based on event
                    return anotherMethod;
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I was hoping to be use enzyme's `.setProps({...})` after I do a `.find()` to get the child component but that isn't supported.

Test code looks like:

```
it('test', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Toolbar/>);
    const child = wrapper.find(ComponentC);
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    child.setProps({onChange: onChangeMock}); // invalid
    child.props().onChange = onChangeMock; // invalid

    expect(onChangeMock.mock.calls.length).to.be(1);
    // additional validation to ensure my logic in component is correct
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see whether ComponentC's method is called, I suggest to use Sinon spy here.

If you change Toolbar like this:

```
class Toolbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    do something here... 
  }

  render() {
    ...and here...
  }

  renderItem() {
    return (
      <ComponentC
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.handleChange(event);
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

When you have done that, you can spy Toolbar's handleChange method like this:

```
const onChangeSpy = sinon.spy(Toolbar.prototype, 'handleChange');
```

And then in test you have to actually simulate the change in order the onChange function to be called. You can achieve that like this:

```
child.simulate('change');
```

Finally, check if spy was called:

```
expect(onChangeSpy.calls.length).toEqual(1);
```